# How to deal with different data types when parsing a general CSV read function? (without specifying them explicitly)

Tags: c++

How to deal with different data types when reading in data from an arbitrary CSV?

That is, how to deal with the different data types without specifying them explicitly?

Comment: You can't. You have to specify what types will appear, how to figure out which bytes mean which types and how to parse them. You can define that everything is a string or that all numbers are `double`s to combine some cases. Ultimately it depends on what you want to do with the data (printing it to console and calculating the average would be very different requirements), but you didn't state that in the question.

Comment: CSV doesn't really have different data  types. That is to say that everything could potentially be a string, and the same column can contain things that can be numeric and things that cannot be.

Comment: @nwp I am trying to build a general parser. I thought of using throw catch for each vector however that would be very messy... Some data in the CSV could be a std::string, other would be int or float. Trying to understand how to achieve this without specifying the data types manually and without using throw catch statements which try to cast the whole vector.

Comment: @Dave The usual approach is to write a parser that treats everything as a string - here's one I wrote earlier: https://bitbucket.org/neilb/csvparse/src. It's then up to the application code that uses the parser to check for validity (which you have to do anyway) and perform the desired conversions from strings to other types.

Comment: `throw` `catch` is not the correct approach for this. If `std::string`, `int` and `float` are the types that you need to support and you need to support arithmetics then you should make a type that can hold those data types, can be initialized with either of these types, remembers which type it is and supports the operations. Some variant type probably. Or you just use [some library](https://github.com/search?utf8=✓&q=csv+parser+language%3AC%2B%2B&type=Repositories&ref=advsearch&l=&l=).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `std::any` - See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any.

Store the values into an `std::vector<std::vector<std::any>>`

Comment: I'd argue that variant would be a better fit, since the set of types that can be put in CSV is fixed

Comment: The parser may parse certain entries into other type - perhaps Colour?